# git: What are references @{like this} called?

Tags: git

With git, I've used "references" with at sign and curly braces, like `@{UPSTREAM}` or `@{PUSH}`, but I can't find them in https://git-scm.com/docs.

Where can I find an exhaustive list of them and their descriptions?

Comment: This isn't about shell syntax; it's about Git syntax described in the `gitrevisions` man page.

Comment: I find both of them documented here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Comment: I'm afraid this syntax doesn't seem to have any cool name; the docs just say things like "A ref followed by the suffix @ with a ... specification enclosed in a brace pair".

Comment: Here is [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emem).

Comment: @evolutionxbox : `@{...}` ref names are git specific, and aren't the same as `${var...}` (parameter expansion in bash)

Comment: thank you all for the corrections there 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man gitrevisions` ([that page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) on git-scm.com/docs) simply refers to it as "the @ construct". It's one of several constructs (collectively referred to, I think, as *extended SHA syntax*) used to construct "names" that resolve to one or more SHA hashes.